# How to get terms of a custom post type in a loop inside footer.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post type called 'map' and registered a new taxonomy for it. Now, I need to get, through a loop, every term of 'map'. So far, I had a "invalid taxonomy" which I do not understand why so. Everything is working perfectly except this!

How I register my new taxonomy (in functions.php):

```
function create_map_taxonomy() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Map_Category', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Map_Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'parent_item'                => null,
            'parent_item_colon'          => null,
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Map_Category Name', 'textdomain' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Map_Category with commas', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'No Map_Category found.', 'textdomain' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Map_Category', 'textdomain' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'labels'                => $labels,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'map_category', 'map', $args );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_map_taxonomy', 0 );
```

And this is my code in footer.php:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'map',
    );

    $map_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($map_query->have_posts()) : $map_query->the_post();

        $img_background = get_field('image_background');
        $cat = get_terms(get_the_id(), 'map_category');
        var_dump($cat);

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

The result is always "invalid taxonomy". But how is it a invalid taxonomy when I can see it in admin pages?

Comment: You are trying to get terms earlier than taxonomy is registered.

Comment: How's that even possible? My code to retrieve the terms are in footer.php. How could I fix this?

Comment: Try to remove priority from `add_action()` or at least make it >= 1. I don't think zero is allowed. I am not sure, I don't know what happens in the footer except what I see here.

Comment: I changed the priority from add_action() but I still have the same errors : invalid taxonomy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) is not the function you need. This function retrieves an array of WP_Term objects for all terms within the given taxonomy

Update your code to use [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) instead of `get_terms`. You can keep the same parameters. This function will retrieve the terms used on the current post.

Comment: EXACTLY! I was reading everything about hooks and filters because I thought it was an issue with the priorities. But I was wrong! A thousand thank you for you sir, you saved my day!